# How to use substitution in xargs?

Tags: shell, xargs

What I want to do is

1. find all file with `.txt` extension
2. cp them to `.dat` file

it could do like this:

```
for f in `find . -type f -name "*.txt"`; do cp $f ${f%.txt}.dat; done
```

I want to do this with xargs, I have tried this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs -i cp {} ${{}%.txt}.dat
```

I go error like this:

```
bad substitution
```

About this, I have these questions:

1. **how to do the substitution rightly?**
2. **I am curious about that `xargs` will do things parallel when `for loop` do things one by one?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> 1. How to do the substitution rightly?

You cannot use substitution in the way you are trying to do because `{}` is not a bash variable (only part of xargs syntax), therefore bash cannot do substitution on it.

A better way to it would be to create a full bash command and provide it as and argument to xargs (e.g. `xargs -0 -i bash -c 'echo cp "$1" "${1%.txt}.dat"' - '{}'` - this way you *can* do bash substitution).

> 2. I am curious about that xargs will do things parallel when for loop do things one by one?

Yes, `for` loop will do things sequently but by default xargs always will. However, you can use `-P` option of `xargs` to parallelize it, from `xargs` man pages:

> ```
>    -P max-procs, --max-procs=max-procs
>           Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at a time.  Use the -n option or the -L  option
>           with  -P;  otherwise  chances are that only one exec will be done.  While xargs is running, you can send its process a
> ```
>
> SIGUSR1 signal to increase the number of commands to
> run simultaneously, or a SIGUSR2 to decrease the number.  You cannot increase it above an implementation-defined limit (which is
> shown with --show-limits).  You cannot de‐
> crease it below 1.  xargs never terminates its commands; when asked to decrease, it merely waits for more than one existing
> command to terminate before starting another.
>
> ```
> Please  note that it is up to the called processes to properly manage parallel access to shared resources.  For example, if
> ```
>
> more than one of them tries to print to stdout,
> the ouptut will be produced in an indeterminate order (and very likely mixed up) unless the processes collaborate in some
> way to prevent this.  Using some kind of  locking
> scheme  is one way to prevent such problems.  In general, using a locking scheme will help ensure correct output but
> reduce performance.  If you don't want to tolerate the
> performance difference, simply arrange for each process to produce a separate output file (or otherwise use separate
> resources).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 |
xargs -0 -i bash -c 'echo cp "$1" "${1%.txt}.dat"' - '{}'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are unhappy about the `bash -c '...' -` construct, you can instead use GNU Parallel:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | parallel -0 cp {} {.}.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` and other tools are not as flexible as **Perl** for this kind of stuff.

```
~ ❱ find . | perl -lne '-f && ($old=$_) && s/\.txt/.dat/g && print "$old => $_"'
./dir/00.file.txt => ./dir/00.file.dat
./dir/06.file.txt => ./dir/06.file.dat
./dir/05.file.txt => ./dir/05.file.dat
./dir/02.file.txt => ./dir/02.file.dat
./dir/08.file.txt => ./dir/08.file.dat
./dir/07.file.txt => ./dir/07.file.dat
./dir/01.file.txt => ./dir/01.file.dat
./dir/04.file.txt => ./dir/04.file.dat
./dir/03.file.txt => ./dir/03.file.dat
./dir/09.file.txt => ./dir/09.file.dat
```

then instead of `print` function use: `rename $old, $_`

With this **one-liner** you can rename anything you like

---

For forcing the `xargs` with parallel mode you should use `-P` like:

```
ls *.mp4 | xargs -I xxx -P 0 ffmpeg -i xxx xxx.mp3
```

converting all the `.mp4` files to `.mp3` in parallel. So if you have 10 `mp4` then 10 `ffmpeg` is running simultaneously.