# Split file content strings by dash using xargs

Tags: bash, shell, sh, xargs

I need to read a file and split every line into a domain and a application string

```
domain.com-backend
domain.com-frontend
```

For each line I need to call a docker build command (echo just to see the command):

```
cat $FILE | grep '-' | xargs -I {} echo docker build -t {full} -f apps/{domain}/{application}/Dockerfile .
```

So in the example I would expect the output

```
docker build -t domain.com-backend -f apps/domain.com/backend/Dockerfile .
docker build -t domain.com-frontend -f apps/domain.com/frontend/Dockerfile .
```

Comment: Why not use `while` loop and `read` command ?

Comment: @DigvijayS Did not think about it. I need to call the command in a CI, so I used before something like this as a one liner without building a 'real' script.

Comment: Yes, you can write in one line. Update my answer

Comment: is using xargs so important? why not use awk ?

Comment: If you use xargs, you could reach having a hard to read/modify command, in order to modify arguments you have to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45895071/how-to-use-substitution-in-xargs . A while loop can easily be written as one-liner too, if this is your concern, it's the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this loop:

```
while read -r x; do
    echo docker build -t "$x" -f "apps/${x/-/\/}/Dockerfile" .
done < "$FILE"
```

Remove `echo` after testing.

See more for [bash parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

---

In case you want to first filter the file, e.g. there are more lines into there and you want first to `grep "-"` like in your example, you could use this syntax (bash only):

```
while read -r x; do
    echo docker build -t "$x" -f "apps/${x/-/\/}/Dockerfile" .
done < <(grep "-" "$FILE")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo  docker build -t ${line} -f apps/$(cut -d'-' -f1  <<<${line})/$(cut -d'-' -f2 <<<${line})/Dockerfile .
done < "${FILE}"
```

Demo :

```
$while IFS= read -r line
> do
>   echo  docker build -t ${line} -f apps/$(cut -d'-' -f1  <<<${line})/$(cut -d'-' -f2 <<<${line})/Dockerfile .
> done  < test.txt 
docker build -t domain.com-backend -f apps/domain.com/backend/Dockerfile .
docker build -t domain.com-frontend -f apps/domain.com/frontend/Dockerfile .
$cat test.txt 
domain.com-backend
domain.com-frontend
```

Edit : One liner

```
while IFS= read -r line; do   echo  docker build -t ${line} -f apps/$(cut -d'-' -f1  <<<${line})/$(cut -d'-' -f2 <<<${line})/Dockerfile . ; done < "${FILE}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the file on `-` while reading and just invoke your command:

```
while IFS='-' read -r dom app; do
   docker build -t "$dom-$app" -f "apps/$dom/$app/Dockerfile .
done < "$file"
```

Read: [bashfaq how to read a file field by field](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Or you could use `xargs`, if you want:

```
sed 's/^\(.*\)-\(.*\)$/\1-\2 \1 \2/' "$file" |
xargs -n3 sh -c 'docker build -t "$1" -f "apps/$2/$3/Dockerfile"' _
```

or even:

```
sed 's@^\(.*\)-\(.*\)$@\1-\2 -f apps/\1/\2/Dockerfile@' "$file" |
xargs -n3 docker build -t
```